# Dexguard release build throws error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libsuprema_libusb.so" not found

Tags: java, android, exception, .so, dexguard

I am trying to make dexguard release build having libraries .so files so when I attach the debugger

adb logcat throws exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libsuprema_libusb.so" not found

Please any one guide as i am using suprema slim2 biometric scanner and everything works great in simple release but when i make release protected build than face this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the past. Solved by adding the line below in the DexGuard configuration file

```
-keepresourcefiles lib/**.so
```

If you want to be more specific you can use this command instead

```
-keepresourcefiles lib/libsuprema_libusb.so
```

This way only the desired library inside the /lib folder will be kept.

You can find all the different rules explanations in the DexGuard documentation (not public online)